# Add new column with existing column names

Tags: python, pandas, max

I'm dealing with a dataframe which looks like:

```
    FID           geometry                                       Code   w1  w2
0   12776   POLYGON ((-1.350000000000025 53.61540813717482...   12776   0   1
1   13892   POLYGON ((6.749999999999988 52.11964001623148,...   13892   1   0
2   14942   POLYGON ((-3.058896639907732e-14 51.3958198431...   14942   1   1
3   18964   POLYGON ((8.549999999999974 45.26941059233587,...   18964   0   1
4   19863   POLYGON ((-0.4500000000000305 44.6337746953077...   19863   0   1
```

My objective is to add a column, labeled as 'Max', where I'm going to write which w (w1, w2) has got more frequency.

So far I've only managed add a column in which appears the maximum frequency, instead of the name of the column where it appears.

The desired output would be something like this:

```
    FID     geometry     Code   w1  w2   Max
0   12776   ...         12776   0   1    w2
1   13892   ...         13892   1   0    w1
2   14942   ...         14942   1   1    0
3   18964   ...         18964   0   1    w2
4   19863   ...         19863   0   1    w2
```

Furthermore, I'd like to fill with zeros whenever the frequencies are the same, if its possible, at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.where` to choose `0` when they are equal `idxmax(1)` when they are not.

```
df['max'] = np.where(df.w1 == df.w2, 0, df[['w1', 'w2']].idxmax(1))
df

    FID     geometry     Code   w1  w2   Max
0   12776   ...         12776   0   1    w2
1   13892   ...         13892   1   0    w1
2   14942   ...         14942   1   1    0
3   18964   ...         18964   0   1    w2
4   19863   ...         19863   0   1    w2
```

Comment: Great! It works perfect! In the case when I have more than two w's is there any way to do this? Suppose I have six w's... It's really unlikely that all w's are equal, but just in case...

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
(df['w1'] == df['w2']).map({True: 0}).fillna(df[['w1', 'w2']].idxmax(axis=1))
Out[26]: 
0    w2
1    w1
2     0
3    w2
4    w2
dtype: object
```

How it works:

The main part is with idxmax:

```
df[['w1', 'w2']].idxmax(axis=1)
Out[27]: 
0    w2
1    w1
2    w1
3    w2
4    w2
dtype: object
```

This first selects the relevant columns, and returns the index of the maximum (axis=1 for columns). However, it returns the first index in case of ties.

`(df['w1'] == df['w2']).map({True: 0})` fills a series with 0 when `w1==w2`. Remaining values are NaN. So those are filled with idxmax values.

Note: `np.where` is definitely the more logical (and probably faster) choice here. I just like to experiment with other alternatives.

Comment: This is a really smart way to do this, but I'd never think of do it in this way. Thanks!