# Pandas: compare list values and write new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a new question regarding with my [my old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376533/add-new-column-with-existing-column-names). In that post the problem were simplified, having only two w's to compare. Now, suppose I have more than 2, e.g., 3, with frequencies (1,1,0). I would like to check this list and, **if the maximum value**, appears more than one time, write 0, otherwise, write the column label of the maximum value, as in the previous post. I tried to adapt the first answer of that post but I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your attention. :-)

EDITED:

An example of my real df is:

`|FID |geometry|GridCode|catarro|constipado|gripa|gripe|resfriado|resfrio
0  |9592|...     |9592    |1      |0         |0    |3    |     3   |  1`

In this case, the desired output would be:

   `|FID |geometry|GridCode|catarro|constipado|gripa|gripe|resfriado|resfrio| max
0  |9592|...     |9592    |1      |0         |0    |3    |     3   |  1    | 0`

Comment: Are those 0-1 columns?

Comment: Yes, I want to do the stuff over the last 6 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED:

```
# You should drop all extra fields
# don't worry they are still present in original dataframe (df)
words = df.drop(['FID'], axis=1)

# Get maximums for each row
maxes = words.max(axis=1)

# Create new column with the features names with maximum values
df['max'] = words.idxmax(axis=1)

# Create a mask with non-accepted rows
mask = (
    words.values.ravel() == maxes.values.repeat(len(words.columns)).ravel()
).reshape(-1,len(words.columns)).astype(int).sum(axis=1)>1

# Wipe 'max' column in non-accepted rows
df.ix[mask,'max'] = 0
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I apply  `df.filter(regex=r'w\d')` to my df, it returns an empty df, only with the indices column.

Actually I have found my problem, w's are 'words' they aren't w1, w2, w3... I'm gonna try to adapt this code.

Comment: If you tell more about you original task I'm sure I could help you. For example if you're working with words frequencies you could use some of transformers used in machine learning (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer)

Comment: I have updated my first post, sorry for the delay. I'm new around .